# Can I get the list item in dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

There is a list has a dict in it and I need one particular item from the dict look

```
[{'id': 666197885, 'price': '1.1170', 'qty': '20.0', 'quoteQty': '22.3400', 'time': 1634148815292, 'isBuyerMaker': False}]
```

I just need time from this list in normally I would use `list_name["time"]` but this time it gives errors. I couldn't find answer for that and than I realize this thing is not a list its a dict so how can I get the time item from this dict?

Comment: get dict: `my_list[0]`, get item from dict: `my_list[0]["time"]`

Comment: I think you're confusing lists and dicts, cause `list_name["time"]` is not valid; you probably meant `dict_name["time"]`. As well, the title implies you have a list in a dict. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the dictionary within `list_name` first and then access the value by key name from the dictionary, in this case by taking the first element `list_name[0]["time"]`

If you expect the list to grow in size, you can pull out all the times with a simple list comprehension: `times = [i["time"] for i in list_names]`